# How to chain two .then in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I have some issues while using .then in JavaScript. I have a fetch function, and then i use the result to update an array of prices. I would like to make the update function wait for the fetch function to end. I can't succeed. Any ideas ?
thank you

```
function FetchPrices() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("j'entre dans FetchPrices")
        var call = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms='+ GetCoinsListToFetch() + '&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&api_key=55baa6d4b58517d610476c';
        fetch(call)
        .then(function (response) {
            response.json()
            .then(function (value) {
                console.log("je suis dans le .then du fetch")
                var v = value
                pricesList = v;
                console.log(v);
                console.log("fin du fetch")

            });
        });
    })
}
```

```
function UpdatePrices() {
    console.log("j'entre dans UpdatePrices")
    console.log(assetList)
    for (asset of assetList) {
        var tempName = asset.Coin
        tempName = tempName.toUpperCase()
        var temppbtc = pricesList[tempName].BTC
        var temppeur = pricesList[tempName].EUR
        asset.Prixeuro = temppeur
        asset.Prixbtc = temppbtc
        asset.Totaleuro = asset.Quantity * asset.Prixeuro
    }

}
```

```
async function Test2 () {
    console.log("j'entre dans test2");
    await FetchPrices().then(()=>UpdatePrices())
}
```

It seems that it doesnt go with the 2nd function UpdatePrices after finishing the first one FetchPrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function is not called because the promise returned by the first function is not resolved (because `resolve` is never called). You can resolve it manually by calling `resolve()` but you should better simply return the promise created by `fetch` function:

```
function FetchPrices() {
  console.log("j'entre dans FetchPrices")
  var call = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms='+ GetCoinsListToFetch() + '&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&api_key=440f35b466d7a82c3f7f94fd64f6436155c272410055baa6d4b58517d610476c';
  return fetch(call)
    .then(function (response) {
      response.json()
        .then(function (value) {
          console.log("je suis dans le .then du fetch")
          var v = value
          pricesList = v;
          console.log(v);
          console.log("fin du fetch")

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Well seen ! 
I have add resolve() on the line after console.log("fin du fetch") and it seems to be working ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @antonku you should directly make use of the promise returned by `fetch`.

As a rule of thumb, you should only be using `new Promise` when the thing you are trying to return is not already a promise.

```
function FetchPrices() {
  var call = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms='+ GetCoinsListToFetch() + '&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&api_key=55baa6d4b58517d610476c';
  return fetch(call).then(response => response.json())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why mix `async` and `then`? I think it's cleaner if you do something like this.

```
const fetchFn = async () => {
   const {json} = await fetch('your url');
   const data = await json();
   return data;
}
```

and in your test2Fn you do something like this

```
const test2Fn = async () => {
    const pricesList = await fetchFn();
    UpdatePrices();
}
```

Hope this helps too!!!